# Thevenin equivalent of voltage divider bias

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, thevenin

Can anyone explain to me the step by step procedure in finding out the Thevenin equivalent of the Voltage-Divider bias shown.

[image: Voltage divider bias]

Comment: You set the question then you are questioning the question. This does not make it easy to answer!

Comment: Well... Let me delete the last part

Comment: That's OK, my answer ignored this bit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the load is the node looking into the base of the transistor. If I'm correct, then it boils down to changing the voltage divider (R1 and R2) into a single resistor in series with a new voltage source.

Firstly the new voltage source - it is the open circuit voltage at the junction of  R1 and R2 when the base is disconnected i.e. Vcc*(R2/(R1+R2)).

And the equivalent source resistance is R1 || R2 i.e. R1*R2/(R1+R2).

Anyway that's my take on it.

Comment: So the two nodes are (i) the one looking into the base and (ii) the ground. Right?

Comment: That's what it seems to me.